# Я ответила B и F Но не уверена в верности ответа. Подскажите правильный ответ

Tags: c#

You are testing an application. The application includes methods named Calculatelnterest and LogLine. The `Calculatelnterest ()` method calculates loan interest. The `Logl_ine()` method sends diagnostic messages to a
console window.
The following code implements the methods. (Line numbers are
You have the following requirements:

- The `Calculatelnterest()` method must run for all build configurations.
- The `LogLine()` method must run only
  for debug builds.

You need to ensure that the methods run correctly.
What are two possible ways to achieve this goal? (Each correct answer presents a complete solution.
Choose two.)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее варианты ответов на приложенных картинках.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Код читать невозможно. Можете его текстом вставить?

Comment: ответы тоже не форматированы. Почему какие то строки отмечены жирным? ЧТо такое `DE30G`?

Comment: ну и, лучший способ найти ответ - это вставить каждый из вариантов в студию и проверить.

Comment: @ValeryLosev пишите ответы ответом, а то повиснет же вопрос.

Comment: Только ответ лучше поподробнее расписать.

Comment: https://exambraindumps.com/70-483.html    Microsoft.70-483.v2015-04-10.by.Ben.59q.ote Упорно отказывается принимать этот ответ за верный. Вот у меня и возникли сомнения. Но спасибо в любом случае

Answer (score 2):

Все верно. Вы правильно ответили)
**UPD**: Расписываю конкретно, почему ответ правильный:

1. Неправильно, т.к. `#region` используется в основном для читаемости кода и не влияет никак на среду выполнения;
2. Правильно, т.к `Conditional("DEBUG")` указывает, что надо игнорировать метод, если он не соответствую среде выполнения(указанной в скобах);
3. Неправильно, см. п. 1;
4. Неправильно, т.к. в данном случае оба метода будут запускаться только в `DEBUG`, а нам необходимо запускать только `LogLine`;
5. Неправильно, т.к. будет игнорироваться метод `CalculateInterest`, а не `LogLine`;
6. Правильно, препроцессор `#if DEBUG` захватывает как раз метод `LogLine', который на и нужен;
7. Неправильно, т.к. в этом случае метод `LogLine` будет работать только в `Release`, а нам надо, чтобы он работал только в `DEBUG`

Comment: https://exambraindumps.com/70-483.html Вопрос возник с того, этот сайт упорно отказывается принимать этот ответ за верный.

Comment: @Софья это брейндампы. В них случаются ошибки